# How to get a whole sqlite3 query onto a tkinter page

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

I am making a program where you can search a name, and everything from the sqlite3 database will show up.

```
def search():
tk = Tk()
tk.geometry('500x500')
labe = Label(tk, text="Search all: fullname, major, gender, class one, class two, class three")
labe.pack()
ent = Entry(tk, bd=5)
ent.pack()
def dog():
    getted = ent.get()
    conn = sqlite3.connect('friend.db')
    if getted == "fullname":
        with conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT name1 FROM Photos')
        conn.commit()
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        for r in result:
            tkee = Tk()
            tkee.geometry('500x500')
            lab = Label(tkee, text=r)
            lab.pack()
            tkee.mainloop()

buty = Button(tk, text="Submit", command=dog)
buty.pack()
```

The program works fine when I enter that I want all the full names, but only one name comes up on the slide. It is only until I exit all the other tabs that the other names show up. If anyone knows how to do this, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks, Jamal

Answer (score 0):

The problem that is occurring is that you are using a for loop.

```
result = cursor.fetchall()
for r in result:
        tkee = Tk()
        tkee.geometry('500x500')
        lab = Label(tkee, text=r)
        lab.pack()
        tkee.mainloop()
```

If you change it just to.

```
result = cursor.fetchall()
tkee = Tk()
tkee.geometry('500x500')
lab = Label(tkee, text=result)
lab.pack()
tkee.mainloop()
```

Then it will work